# Can't use NSJSONSerialization to convert number to JSON value

Tags: ios, json, swift, afnetworking, nsjsonserialization

I need to POST a JSON number value to server, by using AFNetworking, I did it like this :

```
let url:Int = "my_url_here"
let param = myNumber

let task = self.sessionManager.POST(url, param, success:mySuccessBlock, failure:myFailureBlock)
```

Got an exception:

> 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** +[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:options:error:]: Invalid top-level type in JSON write'

After set a exception breakpoint, code stop at `[mutableRequest setHTTPBody...]`：

```
#pragma mark - AFURLRequestSerialization
- (NSURLRequest *)requestBySerializingRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
                           withParameters:(id)parameters
                                    error:(NSError *__autoreleasing *)error
{
......
**[mutableRequest setHTTPBody:[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:parameters options:self.writingOptions error:error]];**
......
}
```

So `[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:options:error:]` can't be used to convert Int/NSNumber to JSON?  What should I do?

Comment: You would generally have something like `let param = ["my_key" : myNumber]`, which would generate JSON that looks like `{"my_key":42}` (or whatever). What do you expect the JSON to look like if you only provided a number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Minimally valid JSON is `{}` or `[]`. You need to wrap the number in an object or an array.

Try `let param = [myNumber]` or `let param = ["number" : myNumber]`, for example.

You can use a tool like [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) to validate your JSON.